# taskmgr.exe 100% CPU Usage

Tags: windows-server-2003, kernel, cpu-usage

I have 2 IBM servers Intel Xeon Dual core with > 2gb RAM.

the problem is that Taskmanager uses one full core when i open it.
The same happens when i copy files in the explorer.

[image: taskmgr.exe using 1 core (25%)]
<sub>(source: [bghupdate.com.ar](http://www.bghupdate.com.ar/chasco/taskmng.jpg))</sub>

[Threads in procexplorer http://www.bghupdate.com.ar/chasco/threads.jpg](http://www.bghupdate.com.ar/chasco/threads.jpg)

OS: Windows 2003 Server

Things i tried:

1. Installed all updates
2. They has kaspersky anti virus and they previously had Nod32.
3. All drivers installed OK.
4. All unused devices are disabled in the bios. (Planar SCSI, Serial Ports, LPT, Audio, Unused networks)
5. Reinstalled win 2003 SP2.
6. No conflict in drivers
7. Tried opening via remote desktop and the problem continues.
8. Updated Bios and Scsi firmware to latest versions
9. Updated all drivers from IBM

The cpu utilization is in the Kernel Times (Red in taskmanager)
If i open Proces Explorer and i navigate to the threads consuming CPU the stack traces ends always in "NtkrnlPA!UnexpectedInterrupt", all threads stacks end in "UnexpectedInterrupt"

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KiUnexpectedInterrupt+0x48
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x20e
ntoskrnl.exe!CcSetReadAheadGranularity+0x1ff9
ntoskrnl.exe!IoAllocateIrp+0x3fd
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x20e
ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x94
ntoskrnl.exe!DbgBreakPointWithStatus+0xe05
ntdll.dll!KiFastSystemCallRet
kernel32.dll!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
taskmgr.exe+0xeef6
kernel32.dll!GetModuleHandleA+0xdf
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the kaspersky anti virus, i desinstalled it and everything went back to normal..

Comment: I have seen this behavior with other antivirus software on desktop versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Two questions -

have you tried Process Explorer?

"All unused devices are disabled in the bios." - which devices are these?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from your list - have you installed *updated* drivers and BIOS firmware?

I've had this same issue twice in the past (both on Dell servers). Once it was outdated drivers for a video card, the other time it was outdated BIOS firmware.

Comment: Yes, updated in question.